# Not able to access master page control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages, nullreferenceexception

I have this in my Master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BannerPlaceHolder" runat="server">              
 <asp:HyperLink ID="PortalBanner" runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="Images/banner-12-5-11.jpg"   
                NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I want to be able to change the hyperlink `ImageUrl` but  I get a null exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's my code to access the HyperLink

```
ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.Master.FindControl("BannerPlaceHolder");
HyperLink hp= (HyperLink)cp.FindControl("PortalBanner");
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that it is in the `Master` of the `Master`? If not, simply change it to:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("BannerPlaceHolder");
```

Another approach is to provide a property in your master that you can access from your page by casting it to the actual type.

in the master's codebehind:

```
public string PortalBannerImageUrl
{
    get {
        return this.PortalBanner.ImageUrl;
    }
    set {
        this.PortalBanner.ImageUrl = value;
    }
}
```

in the page:

```
var myMaster = this.Master as YourMasterType;
if(myMaster != null)
{
    myMaster.PortalBannerImageUrl = newImageUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , you're right I had to remove the extra Master, is your second approach better then the first one?

Comment: @meda: It's also hard-wiring the page with the master which is not so good. But it's clearer and less error-prone since it doesn't  rely on an ID that might change. So yes, the second approach is normally better even if it's a  little bit more work.You have even intellisense on this property and the name is self-explanatory. So if you (or others) want to access or change this property from other pages as well it's more readable and maintainable and you have compile time safety.

Comment: Okay I get it, but what is `YourMasterType`?

Comment: @meda: Since i didn't know the name of your `MasterPage` i have called it `YourMasterType`. Maybe it's `SiteMaster` or whatever. The name of the class that inherits `System.Web.UI.MasterPage` where you've declared the `ImageButton`.

Comment: Thanks Tim you have answered all my questions!